# Pixels eraser in Processing

Tags: processing

I am new using Processing and this time I am trying to do like a paint program. As I chose to draw a grid in the background, I don't know how to make a eraser. If someone has any ideas....

This is my code:

```
int x = 20, y = 40, w = 70, h = 50;

void setup() {
  size(600, 600);
  background(255);

  stroke(240);
  for (int linex = 0; linex < width; linex = linex+40) {
    for (int liney = 0; liney < height; liney = liney + 40) {
      line(0, liney, width, liney);
    }
    line(linex, 0, linex, height);
  }

  fill(255, 0, 0);
  rect(x, height - 250, w, h);

  fill(0, 255, 0);
  rect(x, height - 190, w, h);

  fill(0, 0, 255);
  rect(x, height - 130, w, h);

  fill(0);
  rect(x, y, w, h);
  textSize(17);
  text("Erase everything", 10, 30);
}

void draw() {
  if ((keyPressed && key == 'r') || (mousePressed && mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > (height - 250) && mouseY < (height - 250) + h)) {
    fill(255, 0, 0);
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 'g'|| (mousePressed && mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > (height - 190) && mouseY < (height - 190) + h)) {
    fill(0, 255, 0);
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 'b' || (mousePressed && mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > (height - 130) && mouseY < (height - 130) + h))  {
    fill(0, 0, 255);
  }
  if (keyPressed && key == 'n'){
    fill(0);
  }

  if (mousePressed) {
    noStroke();
    ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
  }

  if (mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > y && mouseY < y+h && mousePressed) {
    setup();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: As the person who maintained Processing.js for years, I have lots of ideas, but you need to be a bit more specific: there is no relation between "drawing a grid" and "making an eraser", so what's the _actual_ problem you're having? Also, _never_ call `setup()`, that function is a one-time function that Processing uses to start everything up. Anything you need to draw, you put in `draw()`, because Processing _always_ calls `setup` and then `draw`, on startup, and then as long as you didn't issue `noLoop()`, will keep calling `draw` on a loop.

Comment: So looking at your code: put that drawing code in `draw()`, and start using event handlers instead of using `draw()` as your event handler. As a "paint-like", your program does _not_ need to redraw at 60 fps, it needs to do "nothing" most of the time, so you write a `setup()` with `noLoop()` at the end, you put your actual "draw this" code in `draw()`, you add event handlers like `void mousePressed() { ...; ...; ...;  redraw(); }` and then that `redraw()` call will make sure that your sketch only updates if and when it has to update. E.g. https://www.processing.org/examples/redraw.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just sneak the following code somewhere into the draw() function in your program.

```
noStroke();

ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 8, 8); // change width and height to the diameter (in pixels) you want your eraser to have.

strokeWeight(1);
```

Or, if you want a square instead of a circle:

```
noStroke();
rectMode(CENTER);

rect(mouseX, mouseY, 8, 8);

rectMode(CORNER);
strokeWeight(1);
```

Or something in beetween:

```
noStroke();
rectMode(CENTER);

rect(mouseX, mouseY, 8, 8, 4); // the 5th parameter is the edge smoothness (in pixels)

rectMode(CORNER);
strokeWeight(1);
```